# rsync: Include and Exclude

Tags: linux, rsync

Assuming the following structure, that needs to be rsync'ed:

```
 /Data
   /subDir1
      A.html
      /subDir1a
         AA.html
   /subDir2
      B.html
   1.txt
   2.txt
   2.txt~

rsync -aAHSXrv --include-from=$InExCL $Source $Destination
```

Now I want to IN- and EXclude stuff in the InExCl.list using + and -:
This works fine, files 2.txt and 2.txt~ show up in the backup, 1.txt does not:

```
+ 2.*
- *.txt
```

For the sub-directories I tried it similar (first the plus, the the minus) in order to EXclude subDir1 but to include subDir1a with AA.html and subDir2 with B.txt:

```
+ subDir1a/*
- subDir1/*
```

The result: subDir2 is fine, subDi1 shows up empty and subDir1a is not even mentioned.

Anybody to advice me, how this can be done right? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of is to put a `.rsync-filter` file in
`Data/subDir1/` containing the following three lines.

```
include /*/
exclude /*
exclude /.rsync-filter
```

The first one will include all directories in this file while
the second one will exclude everything. The order is important here
because the first rule that matches is applied. So the first line ensures
that all directories are processed even though we wish to exclude all non-directory files in `Data/subDir1/`.

The *rsync* man page has all the details. Just look for *--filter* and 
*FILTER RULES* in it.

```
Data
├── 1.txt
├── 2.txt
├── 3.txt
├── subDir1
│   ├── A.html
│   ├── .rsync-filter
│   └── subDir1a
│       └── AA.html
└── subDir2
    └── B.html
```

After the command `rsync -rvt -F Data/ dest`

The option `-F` makes *rsync* consider *.rsync-filter* files
present in each directory.

dest looks like below.

```
dest
├── 1.txt
├── 2.txt
├── 3.txt
├── subDir1
│   └── subDir1a
│       └── AA.html
└── subDir2
    └── B.html
```

Comment: @StOMicha, yes, your solution does the same thing. It is just a matter of which way one prefers.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you chandra,

just now I found another solution which seems to work for the directories:

```
+ subDir1/subDir1a
- subDir1/*
```

in regards to the subdirectories, your result (and the desired) ia achieved

```
├── subDir1
│   └── subDir1a
│       └── AA.html
└── subDir2
    └── B.html
```

What do you think?